# Why does this Kotlin method have enclosing backticks?

Tags: kotlin, methods, keyword, backticks

What are the backticks used for in the snippet below?

Why add them around the `fun is(amount:Int ):Boolean { ... }`?

```
verifier.`is`(amount)
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

It's because `is` is a reserved keyword in Kotlin. Since Kotlin is supposed to be interoperable with Java and `is` is a valid method (identifier) name in Java, the backticks are used to escape the method so that it can be used as a method without confusing it as a keyword. Without it it will not work because it would be invalid syntax.

This is highlighted [in the Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin):

> #### Escaping for Java identifiers that are keywords in Kotlin
>
> Some of the Kotlin keywords are valid identifiers in Java: `in`, `object`, `is`, etc. If a Java library uses a Kotlin keyword for a method, you can still call the method escaping it with the backtick (`) character
>
> ```
> foo.`is`(bar)
> ```

Comment: I'd also like to add that "in the wild", this is often used to have _identifier names with spaces_ in them, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58955270/771032).

Answer (score 25):

### Useful for tests

Backticks are very useful in tests for long function names:

```
@Test
fun `adding 3 and 4 should be equal to 7`() {
    assertEquals(calculator.add(3, 4), 7)
}
```

This makes the function names more readable. We can add spaces and other special characters in the function names. However, remember to use it only in tests, it's against the Kotlin coding conventions of the regular code.

Answer (score 12):

It allows you to call a Java method whose name is a Kotlin keyword. It won't work if you leave out the backticks.

Answer (score 12):

The backtick are a "workaround" to allow you to call methods that have a name representing a Kotlin keyword.

See [kotlinlang](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html):

> Some of the Kotlin keywords are valid identifiers in Java: in, object, is, etc. If a Java library uses a Kotlin keyword for a method, you can still call the method escaping it with the backtick (`) character

Answer (score 2):

`is` in list of Kotlin reserved [words](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/compiler.common/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/renderer/KeywordStringsGenerated.java)
To use Kotlin reserved word (such as `is` or `object`) for function/class name you should wrap it to backticks

Answer (score 2):

> Some of the Kotlin keywords are valid identifiers in Java: in, object, is, etc. If a Java library uses a Kotlin keyword for a method, you can still call the method escaping it with the backtick (`) character

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html