# Kafka Streams Materialized View with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

To create a kafka streams state store in Java I can do this:

```
final KGroupedStream<String, String> wordCounts = textLines
            .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(pattern.split(value.toLowerCase())))
            .groupBy((key, word) -> word);

wordCounts.count(Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(WORD_COUNT_STORE));
```

I am attempting to convert this to Kotlin, like this:

```
val wordCounts: KGroupedStream<String, String> = textLines
        .flatMapValues({value -> value.split("\\W+") })
        .groupBy({ _, word -> word})

wordCounts.count(Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, Array<Byte>>>as(WORD_COUNT_STORE))
```

However, I get the following compiler error:

```
Interface KeyValueStore does not have constructors
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this Kotlin method have enclosing backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149474/why-does-this-kotlin-method-have-enclosing-backticks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `as` is a reserved word in Kotlin, try surrounding the `as` with backticks i.e.

```
`as`
```

Answer (score 4):

In case it's of use to anyone else, as well as the backticks suggested by Raman, I had to make couple of other changes:

- First, the generic types need to be specified after the `as` method, not straight after the `Materialized` class.
- Secondly, rather than using `Array<Byte>` I had to use `ByteArray`.

So the full line of code that worked for me was:

```
wordCounts.count(Materialized.`as`<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>(WORD_COUNT_STORE))
```