# How do I call Scala sealed traits from Kotlin?

Tags: scala, kotlin

From what I've read, Scala sealed traits can be used for ENUM like behavior, but they are not as intuitive to use in Java or Kotlin.

Scala code (and [Suzy MV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-K5gDJlTVk))

```
package com.example

sealed trait Answer
case object Yes extends Answer
case object No extends Answer
case object Maybe extends Answer
```

Java code to call above Scala

```
import com.example.Yes$;
Yes$ myAnswer = Yes$.MODULE$;
```

How do you call this in Kotlin?

Comment: Sealed traits are not enums, but it can be used to achieve an enum-like behavior ([almost](https://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums/)).

Comment: Corrected the description. I don't know Scala, the devs on my team use it, while I automate tests in Kotlin. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Refer to [Why does this Kotlin method have enclosing backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44149474/6521116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backticks are your friends here!

Kotlin

```
import com.example.`Yes$`
`Yes$`.`MODULE$`
```