# Why does Kotlin data class objects have backticks?

Tags: android, kotlin, keyword, backticks, data-class

This is my data class created using a Kotlin data class creator Plugin.

```
data class ResponseHealthInisghts(
val `data`: List<Data>,
val message: String,
val statusCode: Int
)
```

This code gets work even if I remove the backticks, I wonder if it's for Java interoperability. But this variable is not a keyword but also it has backticks. why? 
Based on [Why does this Kotlin method have enclosing backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149474/why-does-this-kotlin-method-have-enclosing-backticks)
this question `is` is a keyword for both Java and Kotlin but **data** is not.

Comment: @NileshRathod Can you re-evaluate duplication? `is` is a hard keyword and `data` isn't

Comment: @KrisRoofe Did you see the last portion of my question? I have already mentioned that question here.

Comment: @ManojPerumarath sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this question's answer[Why does this Kotlin method have enclosing backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149474/why-does-this-kotlin-method-have-enclosing-backticks)
and the comments from @forpas and @marstran I was able to understand my problem.

The `is` keyword is a **hard keyword**

> **Hard Keywords**
> are always interpreted as keywords and cannot be used as identifiers:

so fore interoperability we need to use backticks because Java and Kotlin both have `is` keyword.

Where `data` keyword is only available in `Kotlin` and also belong to the category

> **Soft Keywords**
> act as keywords in the context when they are applicable and can be used as identifiers in other contexts.

So we can use it with or without backticks.

Also as an additional note you can use bacticks to customize your identifier

```
var `data is simple` : List<String>
```

If it shows lint error use

> "File | Settings | Editor | Inspections | Illegal Android Identifier" and disable this inspection.

Answer (score 5):

You can use backticks simply to enclose class, method or variable name

For example it's useful if there are spaces:

```
class `Final Frontier` {
    fun `out of space`() {
        val `first second`: String?
    }
}
```

Or as you mention if using [Kotlin keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149474/why-does-this-kotlin-method-have-enclosing-backticks)

> If a Java library uses a Kotlin keyword for a method
>
> ```
> foo.`is`(bar)
> ```

`data` is a [Modifier Keyword](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#modifier-keywords)

> data instructs the compiler to generate canonical members for a class
> The following tokens act as keywords in modifier lists of declarations and can be used as identifiers in other contexts

And **not a Hard Keyword** that can't be used as identifier

> The following tokens are always interpreted as keywords and cannot be used as identifier

Answer (score 2):

It allows you to use reserved keywords and operators as names of your variables. The list of those words: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that, i couldn't understand the above answer

Comment: `data` is a modifier keyword. As you have used `data class` convey a special meaning to the compiler.
While converting your Java code to Kotlin the converter did not change the variable name in your source rather enclosed it in backticks for proper compilation

Comment: Java does not have a keyword `data` hence it is fine to keep `data` as a variable name in Java. But in Kotlin you cant achieve the same without backticks

Comment: @ArkaPravaBasu but what about 'is', it's a reserved keyword in Java, then how?

Comment: data is a *Modifier Keyword* and not a reserved word: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#modifier-keywords

Comment: You can use `data` without backticks here, because it's a soft keyword. This example runs fine: https://pl.kotl.in/t78k70IHx